# Can you specify which instance to terminate when scaling down EC2 instances via autoscaling groups when Termination Policy not followed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to scale down auto scaling groups so that I only remove old instances. I set the termination policy to `OldestInstance` but I think in an effort to keep AZ's balanced, the ASG still takes down new instances instead of old instances.

Is there some way to selectively just specify which instances to kill?

Answer (score 1):

No (but Yes).

When Auto Scaling scales-in, it first chooses an AZ with the most instances (to remain balanced). Then, within the chosen AZ, it uses the [Termination Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#custom-termination-policy) to determine which instance to terminate.

However, rather than having Auto Scaling terminate an instance through a scale-in event, you can **specifically remove an instance from an Auto Scaling group** with [`terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group.html). This command will mark an instance for termination and, optionally, decrement the desired capacity so that the instance is *not* replaced.